# Remove mandatory Address field from Signup Page :Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

i am able to delete non-required fields like: address2, but how can i remove mandatory Address field from Signup Page only, and so that then it ask address only on checkout page.

So, after disabling Address field, we have to make changes on checkout page to ask address mandatory.
I am learning php MVC, and really excited how can i do this.

Answer (score 3):

**Step : 1**

> Path : catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/register.tpl

**Step : 2**

Remove Lines: 249-263

OR

**Find below lines and remove them.**

ADDESS - 1 :

```
<div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-address-1"><?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_1; ?>" id="input-address-1" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
```

ADDESS - 2 :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-address-2"><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_2; ?>" id="input-address-2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. perfect working for you. I tested on my website as well.

Comment: how to delete '  <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-address-1"><?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_1; ?>" id="input-address-1" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>'

Comment: Which is the actual question.

Comment: what you say ? i can't understand ?

Comment: There are two address fields on register page: Address 1 and address 2. i want to remove both fields.

Comment: yes you can remove it easily. above examples is address 2. you can see it.

Comment: i update answer. please check it. don't change model and controller files.

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer. please green mark it.

Comment: on checkout page, First address is selected which i only a name only(bcoz we had remove all other fields: like country+addresses...etc)

Comment: so we need to do canes on checkout page to ask full address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205928/discussion-between-mujahid-bhoraniya-and-anmol-singh).

Comment: Hi Mojahid, can we discuss this problem?

Comment: Imagine we have removed the Complete Address field-set, and now in the account -> Only name will show in a row on Address Book Entries page.   So, at checkout page(i'm using Ajax Quick Checkout by Dreamvention), customer can select that -> only having name field there. So i do not want to proceed checkout with that field has only name.

Comment: Any idea how to handle this situation?